# PRUNE command is not recognised in ArangoDB 3.4.5 for Windows

Tags: arangodb

Updated from 3.4.2 to 3.4.5 Community Edition for Windows in order to use PRUNE option. I'm trying now to write a traversal using PRUNE in ArangoDB Web Interface but the parser does not recognise this command (simply the word remains black instead of blue as any AQL keyword in the query).
Has someone faced the same problem?

Comment: include your code you use to initiate command. Any error-logs to post as well?

Answer (score 0):

A step forward. The PRUNE keyword is correctly parsed (even if its colour remains black) only when it is the first filter in a traversal. In this case it seems to work appropriately, instead the parser returns an error when PRUNE is preceded by OPTIONS or FILTER.

Comment: The Web UI doesn't use the actual parser. It runs on the client-side and has basic syntax highlighting. The actual parser is on the server-side. The Web UI is simply lacking the `PRUNE` keyword here: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/devel/js/apps/system/_admin/aardvark/APP/frontend/src/mode-aql.js#L90

Comment: The issue has been addressed and will be resolved in v3.4.6 and v3.5.0: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/pull/8781